# Where to ask a question about iTunes/AppStore

Tags: support, closed-questions, off-topic

I had asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/441430/itunes-connect-how-to-delete-new-version-of-in-app-purchase) some time back and it had been closed as off-topic. 
Now I have another question related to iTunes and the AppStore.

Can anyone say which stack exchange site would be suitable for the question?

Comment: I voted to close back then because I felt this was a problem specific to the Apple service rather than any actual software issue on your computer. Maybe you can give us more details about what you want to ask. I'm inclined to reopen the question you mention if others agree – I'm just not sure we've ever had questions on actually publishing your own developed stuff on iTunes.

Comment: well..then the question I have in mind NOW is also related to Apple service(as opposed to issue in my sytem).  I wanted to ask about how app ratings in the App Store are displayed in iTunes depending on the user country..  Any suggestions as to where i can ask this question?

Comment: Questions like that should be brought up with Apple support IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly speaking, I don't think there's a Stack Exchange site for this

- It's not fit for Stack Overflow because it's not a programming question
- Ask Different doesn't do questions on iTunes connect
- Super User doesn't do questions related to webservices
- It *may* just narrowly fit [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

I think you're better off dropping by one of [chat rooms on Stack Overflow](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and asking over there. Or as Oliver [mentioned](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5919/where-to-ask-a-question-about-itunes-appstore#comment15188_5919), contact Apple Support or [Apple's Developer forums](https://discussions.apple.com/community/developer_forums)

Answer (score 0):

You could check out http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I thought of that initially, but their [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) says 
`Please refrain from asking about Apple Developer Programs or iTunes Connect (including iAd and the iBookstore)`

Comment: yeah [apple.se] doesn't do such questions